# Stream Encrypted Media Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, video-streaming

Normally, Google Drive allows you to stream video and audio, but is it possible to write an application that streams a video/audio file that has been encrypted/password-protected prior to uploading to Gdrive?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you need to decrypt those video/audio files to be able to stream them.

You may want to check the following for additional insights.

- [Decrypt protected file when viewed on Google docs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21347447/6092067)
- [Encrypting files on Google Drive](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53198/encrypting-files-on-google-drive)
- [Google Drive - Video Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479155/google-drive-video-streaming)